# Self-Learning and trying to return an array with every number incremented by a provided increment

Tags: javascript, methods

Learning to code at the moment and I'm struggling to take an array of numbers and return an array with all of the numbers incremented by a provided increment. Ideally using map..

I have already tried this and I know its neither working nor pretty...

```
const incrementNums = (list, increment) => {
  let incremented = list.map(num => {return num + increment})
};
```

For example...

```
  const list = [4];
  const actual = incrementNums(list, 1);
  const expected = [5];
```

Or...

```
  list = [4, 5, 57, 84];
  actual = incrementNums(list, 1);
  expected = [5, 6, 58, 85];
  expect(actual).to.eql(expected);

  actual = incrementNums(list, 10);
  expected = [14, 15, 67, 94];
```

Comment: `incremented` exits only inside of the function. Perhaps you should `return` it?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't returning anything from that function. Try this:

```
const incrementNums = (list, increment) => {
  return list.map(num => num + increment);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, how would you edit this solution if you are also trying to ensure the same list is returned if no increment is provided?

Comment: just change `num + increment` to `num + (increment||0)`

Comment: Unfortunately that will return [0, 0] if I am trying to simply return a given list [1, 2] as [1, 2].. thanks!!

Comment: Sorry missed brackets, added now

Comment: @JL91 I would change it to this:

`const incrementNums = (list, increment = 0) => list.map(num => num + increment);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
const list = [4, 5, 57, 84]
console.log(list)

const incrementNums = (list, incrementer) => list.map(num => num + (incrementer||0));

console.log(incrementNums(list, 10));
console.log(incrementNums(list));
```

Comment: Thanks John, how would you edit this solution if you are also trying to ensure the same list is returned if no increment is provided?

Comment: Added support and test for undefined increment